# I am trying to return an array sorted in descending order, Is there a reason my code is returning no output to the output file?

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    ifstream inputFile;
    ofstream outputFile;
    string filename;
    const int SIZE = 20;
    float numbers[SIZE];
    int i = 0;
    float temp;
    cin >> filename;

    // Open files and if input file is not open return error message and end program

    outputFile.open("output.txt");
    inputFile.open(filename);
    if (!inputFile)
    {
        cout << "File not found" << endl;
        return -1;
    }

    // Get numbers from input file and sort them from largest to smallest
    while (inputFile >> numbers[i])
    {
        i++;
    }

    for (i = 0; i < sizeof(numbers); i++)
    {
        if (numbers[i] < numbers[i + 1])
        {
            temp = numbers[i];
            numbers[i + 1] = numbers[i];
            numbers[i] = temp;
        }
    }

    // Take numbers in new order and output them to output file

    for (i = 0; i < sizeof(numbers); i++)
        outputFile << numbers[i] << ", ";

    // Close all files
    outputFile.close();
    inputFile.close();

    return 0;
}
```

Write a program that opens a text file to load a sequence of real values, separated by commas and whitespaces. You can safely assume that the number of real values in all the files is less than or equal to 20. The program then sorts these values in the descending order, and outputs the sorted numbers to another text file. The user only enters the input file. This is the problem I am trying to solve.

Comment: we need to see all the code

Comment: Please provide [mcve]. Most likely `sizeof(numbers)` doesn't do what you think it does, but it's hard to say without enough code.

Comment: `while(inputFile >> numbers[i];)` that doesn't even compile. Please show real code.

Comment: you main error is this `sizeof(numbers)` this is the total size of numbers, not the number of elements in it, you need `sizeof(numbers)/sizeof(numbers[0]`

Comment: and your sort is wrong, for a start you loop past then end of the array (numbers[n+1]), second you mean `temp - numbers[i+1]`. PLus you mix in random values if there is less than 20 numbers

Comment: Don't reuse `i` *everywhere*. Declare and use some `n` to count and ascend the number of values read. Then, use `i < n` for the remaining loops that are supposed to be processing numbers you've read into your array during your input loop.

Answer (score 0):

Using modern C++ features makes this much easier than fixed size arrays and keeping track of how many items you've read in.

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <iterator>

int main() {
    std::ifstream in_file;
    std::ofstream out_file;
    
    const std::size_t SIZE = 0;

    std::vector<float> numbers;
    std::string in_file_name;

    std::cin >> in_file_name;

    in_file.open(in_file_name);

    if (!in_file) {
        std::cerr << "File not found" << std::endl;
        return -1;
    }

    std::copy(std::istream_iterator<float>(in_file),
              std::istream_iterator<float>(),
              std::back_inserter(numbers)); 

    in_file.close();

    std::sort(numbers.begin(), numbers.end());

    out_file.open("output.txt");

    std::copy(numbers.begin(),
              numbers.end(),
              std::ostream_iterator<float>(out_file, ", "));

    out_file.close();

    return 0;
}
```